# Pentaho, R Executor insert into DB

Tags: r, pentaho

It is possible to run a R script with Pentaho, but instead of export the result as a csv file, insert the result directly into a table on a DB?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Community Edition of Pentaho, you could use a script executor step to execute a shell script in your OS to do all the work, including inserting to the database, which is not much Pentaho related, all the work is done by the shell script and you just use Pentaho to call the execution of that script.

There's also a very old plugin available in Github that I don't know if it would work with modern versions of Pentaho and R, to execute R code within Pentaho and then continue the stream of data to "normal" steps like the table output to insert the data to a table.

These are the details to configure that plugin from the developers:
http://dekarlab.de/wp/?p=5